# Select multiple counts from Postgres table, convert to Ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Given the following select:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  SUM(CASE approved WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_approved,
  SUM(CASE soft_delete WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_deleted
FROM model_name;
```

How might I translate this into something in my `class ModelName` definition, so that I can retrieve the values of `total`, `num_approved`, and `num_deleted` in my Rails application? I'm happy with any output (array, hash, accessors on a ModelName object) that puts the numbers at the Ruby level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = ModelName.select("
  COUNT(*) AS total, 
  SUM(CASE approved WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_approved,
  SUM(CASE soft_delete WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_deleted
").first

irb(main):278:0> result.total
=> 3041
irb(main):279:0> result.num_approved
=> 199464763
irb(main):280:0> result.num_deleted
=> #<BigDecimal:7fa0b7d79fd8,'0.19365329E8',9(18)>
```

Comment: Will try this when I get in to work tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!